# Is there a way to get the status of a thermal printer using ESC commands?

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer, epson, escpos

I am adding a method to the library [escpos-coffee](https://anastaciocintra.github.io/escpos-coffee/), which returns the status of a thermal printer, i.e. whether it is online/offline, whether the paper is ending or the paper is finished, or whether the cash drawer is open/closed.

I have added a method "showPrinterStatus" to the escpos-coffee library, which is based on the [ESC c 3](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=64) command, which sends the command to the printer in byte form. The Method supposedly enables the Roll paper near end sensor, as well as the Roll paper end sensor. Furthermore, I have added another method "transmitStatus", based on the [GS r](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=124) command, which transmits the paper sensor status for n=1 and n=49, and the status of the cash drawer for n=2 and n=50. Here's the code:

```
 /**
     *
     * @param nSignal
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * Method decides whether the printer should return an output paper-end signal to a parallel interface or not
     * input 1,2 4,8 to enable, 0 to disable
     */

    public EscPos showPrinterStatus(int nSignal)  throws IOException {
        write(27);
        write('c');
        write('3');
        write(nSignal);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param n
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * returns the status of the printer, 1 or 49 returns paper sensor status, 2 or 50 returns drawer kick-out connector status
     */
    public EscPos transmitStatus(int n) throws IOException{
      write(29);
      write('r');
      return this;
    }
```

I am using Device Monitoring Studio, and excpected that there would be some visible communication. It looks like the showPrinterStatus Method is sending a signal to the thermal printer, but the transmitStatus method doesn't seem to cause any communication at all. Also, if I check the cash drawer status und leave the cash drawer open, there is no communication at all, and the request is simply queued. Once I push the cash drawer back in, it takes 5-10 minutes for the command to be executed by the printer, which is still in the queue all this time.

Is there something I am forgetting in my implementation, or is there a better way than Device Monitoring Studio, to display the printer status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I was connected via the usb, try with the serial port and then read from it. Im not a java developer but here is my solution in python

```
from serial import Serial
serial = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=.03)
serial.write(b'\x10\x04\x01')
serial.read()
```

another approach is via the terminal(if you are using linux)

```
echo -n '\x10\x04\x01' > /dev/usb/lp0 #assuming lp0 is your printer 

cat /dev/usb/lp0
```

it outputs the data in the buffer it does not print it on the paper

Comment: echo -n will not work. You have to enable backslash-escaped character interpretation: echo -ne '\x10\x04\x01' > /dev/usb/lp0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using usb interface, you can try to use [usb4java](https://github.com/usb4java) lib, then you can read bytes from the printer, for me it works on linux and show when door is open or paper end..., but i haven't tested it on windows...

```java
UsbEndpoint endpointIn = iface.getUsbEndpoint(endpointAddressIn);
UsbPipe pipeIn = endpointIn.getUsbPipe();
pipeIn.open();
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int received;
received = pipeIn.syncSubmit(data);
pipeIn.close();
```

complete code is on github: [Usb Printer Status](https://github.com/anastaciocintra/escpos-coffee-samples/tree/master/miscellaneous/UsbStatus)